# what http status code should be return when we get error while uploading file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am uploading a file and now I am getting an error when file upload is failed. I want to send an HTTP status code for this error. Is `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` status correct for this?

Comment: How do you decide file upload fails?

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan what do you mean? If he sends an AJAX request it can be dealt with according to the response received... Are you asking Vipul how does he do the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where the error is you might want to send

- 400 If the client malformed his request. (also often considered acceptable if the file was too big)
- 500 If you encountered a problem on the server. (e.g. you cannot copy the file for whatever reason)
- 401 If he is not allowed to upload a file.

Comment: and what if the file is empty ? should we consider 400 in that case ?

Comment: @Vipul From RFC 7231: "The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
   will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
   a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
   message framing, or deceptive request routing)." I think that is exactly the case. So yeah, send 400 when the file is empty.

Comment: Thank you for the info, it was helpful

Comment: @Vipul If my or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more appropriate to return `HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` check the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html#INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).

This will indicate that the server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request which fits the definition of [HTTP 500](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html). You can add more info to the exception returned by server in your error handler code.

Please refer to [this blog](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) for details of how to handle exceptions in Spring MVC